# Google Apps Script: wget or curl authentication

Tags: authentication, curl, google-apps-script, wget

I have a script published as a web app. It uses [Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) and has a `doGet()` function. When I request the script URL from the browser, it returns text. (The returned text is the content of a spreadsheet formatted in a special way, but that's not important here.) So far so good!

```
function doGet(request) {

  // Create text from spreadsheet content...

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(textFromSpreadsheetContent)
}
```

The spreadsheet and web app are both published organisation-wide: Only users of my company have access. This means, the browser requesting the URL must be logged in with a Google Account from my organisation. Also good!

Now I would like to **request the generated text file from the command line**, for example with wget or curl. How do handle the authentication part? wget can submit authentication requests as URL parameters ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)). But it  seems a bad idea to have your Google account credentials in your terminal's history. Also, it won't work well with 2-factor-authentication.

- Is there something like an app-specific authentication token that's less sensitive than the account credentials?
- If not, how else can GET request to a script that's only published organisation wide?

Comment: Although this might be too simple, for example, how about using the query parameters as an authorization code by deploying Web Apps as "Me" for "Execute the app as:" and "Anyone, even anonymous" for "Who has access to the app:"? In that case, you can retrieve and use it by ``request`` of ``function doGet(request) {}``. Or you can also request as a payload of POST method. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike Sounds not too bad. Do I get this right? The sheet stays organisation-private but the web app is public (even anonymous). I publish a key to co-workers. Script checks the key in the get parameter and responds if it's correct. 
I'm wondering, can the script be public when the sheet isn't? And can the public script access the private sheet? EDIT: I checked, yes to both.

Comment: When the Spreadsheet of organisation-private and the script of Web Apps are existing in the same Drive or the script can access the Spreadsheet, users can access the Spreadsheet through the Web Apps. About "can the public script access the private sheet?", if you want to manage each user's Spreadsheet on user's Drive, it cannot be done under the condition of "Me" and "Anyone, even anonymous". Because the condition means that the script of Web Apps is run as owner. I think that this becomes a limitation for using this under your situation.